# proper tensorflow flow_from_dataframe usage with multi-output / multi-label model

Tags: tensorflow, multilabel-classification, multiclass-classification

I'm getting a shape incompatibility at the point of trying to fit my model -- not sure if the issue is with my instantiation of the `DataIterator` or something in my model definition...

[Pastebin of code to reproduce](http://pastebin.com/Fs8UKuLR)

**NOTE: to use code sample above code with the below sample data, you must modify `directory=None` to be `directory=data_sample` and untar `data_sample.tgz` in the same directory you're running this code from**

Run this to train a single prediction head age model:

```
python tf_train_copy.py --csv_file data_sample/dataframe.csv --count 100 --training_type age
```

Run this to train a two prediction  head age and gender model which fails because of the shape-related `ValueError` that this question is for:

```
python tf_train_copy.py --csv_file data_sample/dataframe.csv --count 100 --training_type age_gender
```

[Small sample of 100 images and associated dataframe](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1lT32IVLUYebT_v7hvNgVnhMlAHOpqlJR/view?usp=sharing)

I have a dataframe that looks like this -- with binary `gender` data `{'m', 'f'}` and `age` data that has 3 values:

```
                                                 filename gender mask age_group
218069  /home/lrm/data/VGGFace2_cropped/n005204_0182_0...      f    f  (26, 39)
295315  /home/lrm/data/VGGFace2_cropped/n000162_0085_0...      m    f  (18, 25)
176301  /home/lrm/data/VGGFace2_cropped/n005378_0359_0...      f    f  (26, 39)
212662  /home/lrm/data/VGGFace2_cropped/n006412_0026_0...      m    f  (40, 55)
327910  /home/lrm/data/VGGFace2_cropped/n005114_0240_0...      m    f  (18, 25)
...                                                   ...    ...  ...       ...
283903  /home/lrm/data/VGGFace2_cropped/n002902_0158_0...      m    f  (26, 39)
156748  /home/lrm/data/VGGFace2_cropped/n003909_0464_0...      m    f  (40, 55)
89294   /home/lrm/data/VGGFace2_cropped/n000332_0195_0...      f    f  (18, 25)
156880  /home/lrm/data/VGGFace2_cropped/n005892_0122_0...      f    f  (18, 25)
304084  /home/lrm/data/VGGFace2_cropped/n002321_0114_0...      m    f  (18, 25)
```

and a model defined as such:

```
dense_age = tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=64, activation=tf.keras.layers.ReLU(6.0), name='dense_age')(base_model.output)
dropout_age = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(rate=args.dropout)(dense_age)
pred_age = tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=3, activation='softmax', name='pred_age')(dropout_age)

dense_gender = tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=64, activation=tf.keras.layers.ReLU(6.0), name='dense_gender')(base_model.output)
dropout_gender = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(rate=args.dropout)(dense_gender)
# also tried units=2 for gender prediction
pred_gender = tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=1, activation='softmax', name='pred_gender')(dropout_gender)

model = tf.keras.models.Model(inputs=base_model.input, outputs=[pred_age, pred_gender])
model.compile(
        optimizer=optimizer,
        loss=[tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True, label_smoothing=0.1), tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True, label_smoothing=0.1)],
        metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.Accuracy(name='age_accuracy'), tf.keras.metrics.Accuracy(name='gender_accuracy')])
```

this is how my `DataIterator` object is created:

```
train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_dataframe(
        directory=None,
        dataframe=train_data,
        x_col='filename',
        y_col=['age_group', 'gender'],
        class_mode='multi_output',
        **dataflow_kwargs)
```

and I'm getting a `ValueError` saying there's a shape incompatibility:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tf_train.py", line 385, in <module>
    validation_steps=validation_steps)
  File "/home/lrm/.pyenv/versions/tf_training_231/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/util/deprecation.py", line 324, in new_func
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/lrm/.pyenv/versions/tf_training_231/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py", line 1829, in fit_generator
    initial_epoch=initial_epoch)
  File "/home/lrm/.pyenv/versions/tf_training_231/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py", line 108, in _method_wrapper
    return method(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/lrm/.pyenv/versions/tf_training_231/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py", line 1098, in fit
    tmp_logs = train_function(iterator)
  File "/home/lrm/.pyenv/versions/tf_training_231/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py", line 780, in __call__
    result = self._call(*args, **kwds)
  File "/home/lrm/.pyenv/versions/tf_training_231/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py", line 823, in _call
    self._initialize(args, kwds, add_initializers_to=initializers)
  File "/home/lrm/.pyenv/versions/tf_training_231/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py", line 697, in _initialize
    *args, **kwds))
  File "/home/lrm/.pyenv/versions/tf_training_231/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py", line 2855, in _get_concrete_function_internal_garbage_collected
    graph_function, _, _ = self._maybe_define_function(args, kwargs)
  File "/home/lrm/.pyenv/versions/tf_training_231/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py", line 3213, in _maybe_define_function
    graph_function = self._create_graph_function(args, kwargs)
  File "/home/lrm/.pyenv/versions/tf_training_231/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py", line 3075, in _create_graph_function
    capture_by_value=self._capture_by_value),
  File "/home/lrm/.pyenv/versions/tf_training_231/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/func_graph.py", line 986, in func_graph_from_py_func
    func_outputs = python_func(*func_args, **func_kwargs)
  File "/home/lrm/.pyenv/versions/tf_training_231/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py", line 600, in wrapped_fn
    return weak_wrapped_fn().__wrapped__(*args, **kwds)
  File "/home/lrm/.pyenv/versions/tf_training_231/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/func_graph.py", line 973, in wrapper
    raise e.ag_error_metadata.to_exception(e)
ValueError: in user code:

    /home/lrm/.pyenv/versions/tf_training_231/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:806 train_function  *
        return step_function(self, iterator)
    /home/lrm/.pyenv/versions/tf_training_231/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:796 step_function  **
        outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    /home/lrm/.pyenv/versions/tf_training_231/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:1211 run
        return self._extended.call_for_each_replica(fn, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
    /home/lrm/.pyenv/versions/tf_training_231/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:2585 call_for_each_replica
        return self._call_for_each_replica(fn, args, kwargs)
    /home/lrm/.pyenv/versions/tf_training_231/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:2945 _call_for_each_replica
        return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    /home/lrm/.pyenv/versions/tf_training_231/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:789 run_step  **
        outputs = model.train_step(data)
    /home/lrm/.pyenv/versions/tf_training_231/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:749 train_step
        y, y_pred, sample_weight, regularization_losses=self.losses)
    /home/lrm/.pyenv/versions/tf_training_231/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/compile_utils.py:204 __call__
        loss_value = loss_obj(y_t, y_p, sample_weight=sw)
    /home/lrm/.pyenv/versions/tf_training_231/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/losses.py:149 __call__
        losses = ag_call(y_true, y_pred)
    /home/lrm/.pyenv/versions/tf_training_231/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/losses.py:253 call  **
        return ag_fn(y_true, y_pred, **self._fn_kwargs)
    /home/lrm/.pyenv/versions/tf_training_231/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/util/dispatch.py:201 wrapper
        return target(*args, **kwargs)
    /home/lrm/.pyenv/versions/tf_training_231/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/losses.py:1535 categorical_crossentropy
        return K.categorical_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred, from_logits=from_logits)
    /home/lrm/.pyenv/versions/tf_training_231/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/util/dispatch.py:201 wrapper
        return target(*args, **kwargs)
    /home/lrm/.pyenv/versions/tf_training_231/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/backend.py:4687 categorical_crossentropy
        target.shape.assert_is_compatible_with(output.shape)
    /home/lrm/.pyenv/versions/tf_training_231/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/tensor_shape.py:1134 assert_is_compatible_with
        raise ValueError("Shapes %s and %s are incompatible" % (self, other))

    ValueError: Shapes (None, 1) and (None, 3) are incompatible
```

Comment: why `directory` is `None`? Is the file information embed into the metafiles?

Comment: `x_col` is an absolute path so `directory` is not needed

Comment: Okay, I see. I think activation of `pred_gender` should be `sigmoid`, assuming a column encoded 0 and 1, refer to male and female. And about the `pred_age`, does it contain 3 values or 2 values in a tuple?

Comment: If it's possible, please share a minimum reproducible code.

Comment: Sorry, I can't find the dummy data set if you provide it already. Apart from that, can you add more info about the last layers? You say, `age` has 3 values, typically It probably a regression outputs but you set activation for categorical (`softmax`). In `gender` which probably a binary target vector, but you put activation for categorical (`softmax`).

Comment: @M.Innat `age` has 3 possible string values {'(18, 25)', '(26, 39)', '40, 55'} so it is categorical, not continuous -- `softmax` is an appropriate activation for the final layer. `gender` is also `softmax` as I want the output to be interpreted as a probability. Standby and I will post a sample of the dataframe and images...

Comment: @M.Innat please see the edit to my original post -- I've linked `data_sample.tgz` which has 100 samples. Note: you'll have to update the code to use `directory=data_sample` rather than `directory=None`

Comment: Your data set is not public. Please look.

Comment: I'm able to reproduce your issue. I don't have the exact solution but I think there is something wrong with the data loader. Try `for i, (x,y) in generator: print(y[0], y[0].shape; if i == 0: break` for multi out class mode. It doesn't produce a one-hot vector. You may have to look into it.

Comment: Also,  if `class_mode=multioutput` doesn't do it auto, then you may first need to do that. However, I would recommend you to write a custom data generator. IMO, multi-output with `flow_from_dataframe` is ambiguous.

Comment: hmm, ok I've been playing around with this, tried various combinations of label encoding the `gender` and `age` columns, throwing a wrapper around the generator a la [this article](https://vijayabhaskar96.medium.com/multi-label-image-classification-tutorial-with-keras-imagedatagenerator-cd541f8eaf24) -- getting other different errors -- don't have time to deep-dive into today but I'll update with a solution when I arrive there soon.